# React-Native FusionCharts event won't fire on IOS

Tags: react-native, react-native-ios, fusioncharts

I've implemented a 2d dragable area chart from react-native-fusioncharts. I am trying to fire an event when the data is changed which works as expected on android but no event will fire on IOS.

I've tried dataplotDragEnd and dataPlotClick but neither fire.

```
state = {
   ...,
   events: {
        dataplotDragEnd: (e, a) => {
            Alert.alert("called")
            console.log(e.data.endValue)
          },
        }
     }
}

render() {
  return (
    <FusionCharts
         type={this.state.type}
         width={this.state.width}
         height={this.state.height}
         dataFormat={this.state.dataFormat}
         dataSource={this.state.dataSource}
         events={this.state.events}
         libraryPath={this.libraryPath}
    />
  )
}
```

I am expecting an alert message and a console.log from the event firing but am currently getting nothing only on IOS

Comment: Even this is quite old, I hope this will be helpful to someone.
This issue happened in the older version react-native-fusioncharts. Refer the link.

https://github.com/fusioncharts/react-native-fusioncharts/issues/48